# No audio on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I lost the audio for some reason on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch).

If I do this:
`sudo modprobe snd-bcm2835`

.... I get this:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'snd_bcm2835': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

If I do this.....

`lsusb`

....I see no sound card listed.

.... But if I boot using another memory card and Ubuntu, my sound works just fine. I think I messed up something when I uninstalled all the bluetooth and wifi stuff because I cannot have that running.

Comment: so, did you `see dmesg`? do you have `dtparam=audio=on` in your `config.txt` (not sure if that was present/necessary in such an old version of Raspbian) ... also, the onboard sound device will not show up in `lsusb`

Comment: Hi.  dtparam=audio=on is set, yes.

Comment: On dmesg.... I get this now " snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
"   ....... because I tried to reinstall the driver. Not sure what it said before. Can't I just download and reinstall a driver somehow?

Comment: `snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned` is exactly what is output on all my pi's (from 1 thru to 4) - so, that suggests the module is actually loaded, yet you say it isn't?

Comment: I have only started getting that message in the past hour since I installed the driver from some staging directory. mp123 errors, raspi-config advanced section regarding audio errors, and I don't see the card anywhere.

Comment: mpg123 gives this error.... "connect(2) call to /tmp/jack-0/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
"

Comment: speaker-test -c2 -twav -l7  .... gives this error               "Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
"

Comment: aplay gives this error...   "aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory
"

Comment: you've installed jackd?

Comment: No I have never needed it before as far as I know and didn't want to install some new thing. It's just the error from mpg123, nothing else throws that error.

Answer (score 0):

This did it! Fixed I think.

Opinion of what I did that worked: I think I downgraded the firmware which replaced the driver.

Use this command:
sudo rpi-update e1050e94821a70b2e4c72b318d6c6c968552e9a2

...from here: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1729542#p1729542

NOTE: I then ran rpi-update but it broke again.

So I ran this to get the latest supported kernel (I think)...

sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel

From here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101790/how-to-revert-from-rpi-update-to-stable-build

Summary: I did two steps. Would just the second step have worked? I don't know. Did I run rpi-update a few days ago that broke this all in the first place? Possibly.